# spark sql where clause after select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following spark-sql query:

```
  Seq(("b", 2), ("d", 4), ("a", 1), ("c", 3))
  .toDF("letter", "number")
  .select($"letter")
  .where($"number" > 1)
  .show
```

The original query can even be split up, and the behavior remains:

```
val letters =
  Seq(("b", 2), ("d", 4), ("a", 1), ("c", 3))
  .toDF("letter", "number")
  .select($"letter")

letters
  .where($"number" > 1)
  .show
```

This looks to be related to lazy loading, but, I'm not sure exactly what is happening here.

Why is it possible to include `$"number"` in the where clause, when only letter should remain?

**EDIT 1**
Here is the explain:

```
letters.explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias('letter, None)]
+- Project [_1#76942 AS letter#76955, _2#76943 AS number#76956]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#76942, _2#76943]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
letter: string
Project [letter#76955]
+- Project [_1#76942 AS letter#76955, _2#76943 AS number#76956]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#76942, _2#76943]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [letter#76955]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [letter#76955]
```

Comment: Spark retains the lineage.  Run `letters.explain(true)`.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew I see it, but, I don't know that it tells me much. I'll post it.

Comment: Not so easy to follow, I grant you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherent to the Spark approach, fusing of code within an Action / Job, within a Stage --> narrow transformations.

Spark will optimize the code. Many examples of this.

```
val rdd1 = ...
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(...
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(...
```

When the Action occurs there may not well be even an rdd2, rdd1 due to optimizing and fusing of code, in this trivial example.

In your case, you can fuse it all together and just get a simple Local Table Scan.

You can look at https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/second_generation_tungsten_engine.html to give an idea of fusing code aka Whole Stage Code Generation.

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom. I'll read this over and come back. 

As an aside, I love your profile comment quote "Spark programmer using Scala in Databricks style, not that Monad academic approach." :D

Comment: I am architect who loves programming... Spark is quite smart, still away to go, but very interesting product

Comment: After reading some more, I think you are right WSCG is the reason why the behavior occurs. Thanks for your answer, accepted.